# How to disable the changes made by vba in undo list in MS word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an MS word document, which refer EndNote, MathType, and other things. Each time a reference or equation changes, there will changes added to the undo history.

The history list is full of user-unfriendly records after I delete two lines. The "Undo" loses its function since I never know where I would reach after some unreadable records are "undid". This generated list is so long that I could not find its head, which means I could only "undo" unknown partial of my changes.

I am looking for a solution to skip these "vba" changes.

There was [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832053/dont-add-changes-made-via-vba-to-the-undo-history) with similar topic. The question is not exact same and the link provided in answer does not exist anymore.

Comment: Which version of Word are you using? Is this your VBA or the VBA of the tools you mention? If this is the VBA of the tools you mention then there's nothing you, as an end-user, can do to affect how these tools are writing to the Undo list short of complaining to the software manufacturer. Note that you can continue to "Undo" to the end of the list multiple times - eventually it will undo everything. It's also possible to clear the Undo list, but then you can not undo to a previous point, anymore...

Answer (score 1):

UndoRecords allow you to group the changes.

I don't know how to suspend or remove them from the undo stack altogether however, :(

```
Dim ur As UndoRecord
Set ur = Application.UndoRecord
'Make it easy to undo, rather then spam 50 undo commands.
ur.StartCustomRecord "Remove eform validation formatting"
    For Each 1 To 50
        Selection.TypeBackspace
    Next
ur.EndCustomRecord
```